# boost::asio async_read_some example code not reading all data in the socket

Tags: c++, networking, boost, boost-asio

I'm using the TCP echo example (1.62 is what is currently shipping in the main Ubuntu package).

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp

It works great for small things, you can see it has a buffer of 1024 and uses `async_read_some`.

But then I try to send it the Python string `("A"*4096)+("B"*4096)+("C"*4096)`... I will see 4 calls to the read handler for 1024 bits each... i.e. it will print all the As but never any Bs or Cs.

**Expected behavior:** If there is 4096*3 data in the socket, subsequent calls to `async_read_some` should be pulling all the data out 1024 at a time??

One cannot use `async_read` in such an echo protocol, because variable data is passed over the wire. The problem is `async_read_some` is ignored/deleting data that is still to be read from the socket.

How to fix the example code?

Comment: I told you what happened, no need to get mad

Comment: You told us what happened **and** you claimed various facts that you cannot support with arguments. I'm not mad, I'm suggesting you can improve your question. This will increase the usefulness to others and will increase your problem solving skills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took that sample and ran it with your alleged client code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket

TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 6767
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
MESSAGE = ("A"*4096)+("B"*4096)+("C"*4096);

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.send(MESSAGE)

received = "";
while (len(received) < len(MESSAGE)):
    data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    print "received data: %d bytes ending in ...%s" % (len(data), data[-10:])
    received += data

s.close()
```

It correctly runs and prints

```
 sehe  ~  Projects  stackoverflow  ./sotest 6767&
 sehe  ~  Projects  stackoverflow  python ./test.py
received data: 1024 bytes ending in ...AAAAAAAAAA
received data: 1024 bytes ending in ...AAAAAAAAAA
received data: 1024 bytes ending in ...AAAAAAAAAA
received data: 1024 bytes ending in ...AAAAAAAAAA
received data: 1024 bytes ending in ...BBBBBBBBBB
received data: 1024 bytes ending in ...BBBBBBBBBB
received data: 1024 bytes ending in ...BBBBBBBBBB
received data: 1024 bytes ending in ...BBBBBBBBBB
received data: 1024 bytes ending in ...CCCCCCCCCC
received data: 1024 bytes ending in ...CCCCCCCCCC
received data: 1024 bytes ending in ...CCCCCCCCCC
received data: 1024 bytes ending in ...CCCCCCCCCC
```

So you're doing something wrong.

> Expected behavior: If there is 4096*3 data in the socket, subsequent calls to async_read_some should be pulling all the data out 1024 at a time??

Yes. This is exactly what happens. Mind you, you should not assume the blocks "arrive" in 1024 blocks. They could happen to arrive in smaller chunks depending on the buffering in intermediate OS/network layers. IOW: TCP is a stream protocol and packeting is an implementation detail you should not usually depend on¹

> One cannot use async_read in such an echo protocol, because variable data is passed over the wire.

Data is always variable (otherwise there would be no reason to send it). `async_read` can **always** be used where `read` can be, because it's merely the asynchronous IO version of the same function.

---

¹ using various advanced techniques/flags you can somewhat control these effects but they're partly platform dependent and nearly always operate with margins giving the OS/network layers leeway to optimize network performance.

Comment: I accepted your answer but in reality the demo doesn't work properly across all architectures and operating systems.

Comment: So, I did the same from scratch on your Ubuntu 17.10 version, using the distro boost: [this gif includes installation of boost and gcc](https://i.imgur.com/4suVICR.gif). It's done in 50 seconds. Can you tell us what's different about your environment? I'm pretty sure it's the code that's different, because the code shown should work across all architectures and operating systems.